# 2 buttons pressed at the same time elevator logic

Tags: serial, motor, button

I have currently created a working elevator code where the elevator goes up when pressed a button, and stops at a floor when the sensor senses that it has reached the floor. This is how it works:

```
#define Buzzer 5

#define pwmMot 6

#define halPin 8

#define butto1 9  //level 1
#define butto2 10 //level 2
#define butto3 11 //level 3

#define SeEcho 12
#define SeTrig 13

int button1_status = 0;
int button2_status = 0;
int button3_status = 0;

int current_level = 1;
int required_level =-1;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Buzzer, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Buzzer, HIGH);
  pinMode(halPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(butto1, INPUT);
  pinMode(butto2, INPUT);
  pinMode(butto3, INPUT);
  pinMode(SeTrig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SeEcho, INPUT);
  pinMode(pwmMot, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("you are in level 1");
}

void emergencyStop(){
  analogWrite(pwmMot, 255);
}
int sensor() {
  unsigned long duration;
  int distance;
  digitalWrite(SeTrig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(SeTrig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(SeTrig,LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(SeEcho,HIGH);  
  distance = int(duration/2/29.412);
  return distance;
}

bool hallSen(){
  return digitalRead(halPin);
}

int going_up(){
  while (sensor() > 12){
    analogWrite(pwmMot, 1600);
  }
  return 1;
}

int going_down(){
  while (sensor() > 12){
    analogWrite(pwmMot, 570);
  }
  return 1;
}

void loop() {
  button1_status = digitalRead(butto1);
  button2_status = digitalRead(butto2);
  button3_status = digitalRead(butto3);
  required_level = button1_status == HIGH ? 1 : button2_status == HIGH ? 2 : button3_status == HIGH ? 3 : -1;
  if (required_level != -1 && required_level != current_level){
    while (current_level != required_level){
      if (current_level > required_level) Serial.println("Going Down"), current_level-=going_down();
      else if (current_level< required_level) Serial.println("Going Up"), current_level+=going_up();
      Serial.print("you are in level "); Serial.println(current_level);
      delay(1000);
    }
    analogWrite(pwmMot, 1550); //stop elevator
    digitalWrite(Buzzer, LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(Buzzer, HIGH);
    required_level = -1;
  }
}
```

Now I am just curious as to how I will extend this so that for example if we are in level 1, both the levels 2 and 3 are pressed it should go to level 2 even if level 3 was pressed first. Or if we are in level 2 and both level 1 and 3 are pressed, it should go to the one that is pressed first as both levels are the same distance from level 2.

Comment: when you are at floor 1 you can't just jump to floor 3 you have to pass level 2 first, if you have a sensor there you can simply do something like `if button2 = high && sensor2 = high {do that} else`... i see a state machine in your future!

Comment: definitely a state machine

Comment: @newbie use == instead of =

Comment: @MichelKeijzers right, i was just demonstrating...

Comment: there is no such thing as a "two buttons pressed" scenario as far as the microcontroller is concerned ... the microcontroller checks the buttons sequentially ... that means you have one of two scenarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if we are in level 1, both the levels 2 and 3 are pressed it should go
>   to level 2 even if level 3 was pressed first.

For this to work, the program should remember which buttons (mind the
plural!) have been pressed. Thus, instead of remembering only one
request, as in

```cpp
int required_level =-1;
```

it should have a boolean variable for each of the possible levels,
telling us whether a stop was requested for that level.

For convenience, I would number the levels from zero, and hold these
variables in an array:

```cpp
const int LEVEL_COUNT = 3;
bool requested_stop[LEVEL_COUNT];
```

> if we are in level 2 and both level 1 and 3 are pressed, it should go
>   to the one that is pressed first *as both levels are the same distance
>   from level 2*.

The part I emphasized doesn't make sense to me. The elevator should go
to the one that was pressed first, *irrespective of the distances*.
Imagine you are in an elevator at level 5, and press the button for
level 2. As the elevator just starts moving down, another rider presses
the button for level 6. Should the elevator immediately revert to going
up in order to reach level 6, which is closer? Of course not. If it is
going down, it should continue in that direction. Now, if the other
rider presses 3, it should stop by level 3 on its way down, even though
you pressed 2 first.

As stated by chrisl in a comment, a [finite state machine](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine) is
definitely the solution for this kind of problems. I propose a state
machine with three states, `STOPPED`, `GOING_UP`, and `GOING_DOWN`:

- when `STOPPED`, it should change to `GOING_UP` or `GOING_DOWN` as soon
  as a button for another level is pressed
- when `GOING_UP`, as soon as it reaches a level that has been
  requested, it should change to `STOPPED`
- same thing when `GOING_DOWN`.

And here is my proposed implementation:

```cpp
void loop() {
    // Check the buttons.
    for (int i = 0; i < LEVEL_COUNT; i++)
        if (digitalRead(button[i]) == HIGH)
            requested_stop[i] = true;

    // Finite state machine.
    static enum { STOPPED, GOING_UP, GOING_DOWN } state = STOPPED;
    switch (state) {
    case STOPPED:
        requested_stop[current_level] = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < LEVEL_COUNT; i++) {
            if (requested_stop[i]) {
                if (i < current_level) {
                    analogWrite(pwmMot, PWM_DOWN);
                    state = GOING_DOWN;
                    break;
                } else if (i > current_level) {
                    analogWrite(pwmMot, PWM_UP);
                    state = GOING_UP;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case GOING_UP:
        if (elevator_height() >= LEVEL_HEIGHT[current_level + 1]) {
            current_level++;
            if (requested_stop[current_level]) {
                analogWrite(pwmMot, PWM_STOP);
                state = STOPPED;
            }
        }
        break;
    case GOING_DOWN:
        if (elevator_height() <= LEVEL_HEIGHT[current_level - 1]) {
            current_level--;
            if (requested_stop[current_level]) {
                analogWrite(pwmMot, PWM_STOP);
                state = STOPPED;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This code assumes you have written the function `elevator_height()` that
measures the height of the elevator, and have defined an array of
constants `LEVEL_HEIGHT[]`.

Notice that this is still far from perfect. You should probably ensure
that each stop lasts at least some minimum duration. Otherwise, if the
elevator stops at level 1 while level 0 has also been requested, the
stop will only last an instant. This can be achieved by splitting the
`STOPPED` state in two distinct states, and switching from “waiting for
the riders to go in/out” to “waiting for a button to be pressed” on a
timeout. You may also want to ensure that, after a stop, the elevator
continues in the same direction if possible. Otherwise it will never
reach level 2 if some joker is repeatedly pressing 0 and 1.

Comment: There is a sensor in the elevator and a sensor in each level so instead of the level height logic (we dont have the required sensor to measure the level height) cant we say if elevator sensor matches level sensor and button pressed there then stop?

Comment: @Utsav: Yes. You would just have to replace the condition `elevator_height() >= LEVEL_HEIGHT[current_level+1]` by `elevator_is_sensed_at_level(current_level+1)`. And similarly for the test for `current_level-1`.